# Can't load sparse matrix correctly into Octave

Tags: octave

I have the task to load symmetric positive define sparse matrices from [The University of Florida Sparse Matrix Collection](http://yifanhu.net/GALLERY/GRAPHS/search.html) into GNU Octave. I need to study different ordering algorithms, like [symamd](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/symamd.html) but I can't use them since the matrices are not stored as squared

I have chosen for example [bcsstk17](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/HB/bcsstk17.html).

I've tried different [load methods](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#XREFload) with the .mat files:

```
load -mat bcsstk17
load -mat-binary bcsstk17
load -6 bcsstk17
load -v6 bcsstk17
load -7 bcsstk17
load -mat4-binary bcsstk17
error: load: can't read binary file
load -4 bcsstk17
```

But none of them worked, since my workspace's variables are empty.

When I load the Matrix Market format mtx, *load bcsstk17.mtx* I get  a 219813x3 matrix.

I've tried the [full command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) but I get the same 219813x3  matrix.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're trying to load the `.mtx` file when there's a matlab/octave specific `.mat` format offered there.

Just download the bcsstk17.mat file, and load it:

```
load bcsstk17.mat
```

You will then see on your workspace a variable called `Problem` which is of type struct. This contains several fields, including a `A` field which seems to hold your data in the form of a sparse matrix. In other words, your data can be accessed as `Problem.A`

---

You shouldn't be bothering with the `.mtx` file at all. However for completion I will explain what you're seeing when you load it. The `.mat` file is a binary format. However, a `.mtx` file seems to be a human-readable format (i.e. it contains normal ASCII text). In particular it seems that it consists of a 'header' containing comments, which start with a `%` character, 
a row which seems to encode the size of the sparse matrix in each dimension,
and then it contains "space-delimited" data, where presumably each row represents an element in the matrix, and the three columns presumably represent the row, the column, and the value of that element.

When matlab comes across an ASCII file containing data (+comments), regardless of the extension, as long as the data *seems* like a valid 2D array of numbers, it loads the *data* contents of this file onto a variable with the same name as the file.

Clearly this is not what you want. Not least because the first row will be interpreted as a normal row of data in a Nx3 matrix. In other words, matlab/octave is just loading a standard file it perceives as text-based, and it loads the values it sees inside onto a variable. The extention `.mtx` here is irrelevant as far as matlab/octave is concerned, and it is most definitely not interpreting or decoding the `.mtx` file in any way related to the `.mtx` specification.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I was loading a struct